# Best way to show .mov on a website as load screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, video

What's the best way to show an animation from after effects on a website onload?

It needs to play like a load screen in all major browsers and iOS devices.

What's the best way to show this?

I tried html5 and the auto play didn't work on iPad. I don't want to use flash. The animation is too complex for just JavaScript. Is it worth trying to make a high quality animated GIF?

Comment: A load screen that requires significant loading itself doesn't make for a good user experience. Users want to get to their content as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your main problem with virtually any onload video is going to be load and buffer time, especially on a mobile device. If the splash screen takes half a minute to load, the experience will be very subpar, and there's virtually nothing you can really do to reduce that load time short of making the video low quality (a large animated gif will have the same problem).

My recommendation would be to try coding the animation using pure HTML5 animation effects if possible. They will render faster, use only static images, javascript and CSS, and will be more widely compatible with modern desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to auto-play html5 video on an iOS device. At least as of iOS 5, Apple has disabled both auto-play and pre-loading, presumably to save bandwidth for users who may be on limited or expensive mobile data plans.

Unless you're willing to skip the video, the only workaround is to get the visitor to click or touch something on the page. Mobile Safari will allow you to play a video using Javascript methods (as opposed to the native player controls), but the first call to `.play()` has to come from a "click" or "touch" event handler.

You can limit this requirement to iPads and still allow desktop browsers to auto-play, but there doesn't appear to be any kind of reliable feature-detection method, so you have to parse the User Agent string (`navigator.userAgent`).

There isn't much documentation on the strange, non-standard things Mobile Safari does with video, but this article has some very good, detailed information and some code samples:
http://blog.millermedeiros.com/html5-video-issues-on-the-ipad-and-how-to-solve-them/

**Edit**: And then there's this elaborate and absurd workaround that Apple uses on its own site.
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI